# Why can't we use variables inside a case in switch construct?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

If I have an integer variable like `int a=4` then in the switch case If i write

```
int b = something;
...
switch(a) 
{ 
  case 4+b: printf("hii"); 
}
```

then why is this statement a compile-time error that variables cannot be used inside a case statement why does the compiler not subtitutes the values in place of the variables.

So basically what problem it creates for which the language developers did not include it as a proper syntax.

Comment: `System.out.println()` doesn't look like C.

Comment: Also `case 4+0:` is valid in C.

Answer (score 7):

The initial idea of the `switch` control-flow statement was that it should determine the appropriate case very quickly, while potentially having a lot of cases.

A traditional implementation would use a jump table, making it an `O(1)` operation. The jump table is essentially an array of pointers, where each pointer contains the address of the first instruction for each `case`. Jumping to the appropriate `case` is as simple as indexing that array with the `switch` value and then doing a `jump` instruction to that address.

If the cases were allowed to contain variables, the compiler would have to emit code that first evaluates these expressions and then compares the `switch` value against more than one other value. If that was the case, a `switch` statement would be just a syntactically-sugarized version of a chain of `if` and `else if`.

`switch` statements are usually at the heart of any algorithm which implements a finite-state machine (like parsers), so that was a good reason to include it into the language. Most modern compilers would probably generate identical machine code for a chain of `if` and `else if` which are only testing a variable against a constant, but that wasn't the case in the early 1970s when C was conceived. Moreover, `switch` gives you the ability to fall-through which isn't possible in the latter arrangement.

Comment: Respected Sir,I really appreciate your efforts for explaining me but actually I have still little confusions with the answer you stated regarding the look-up table ,so I would be grateful enough if You could throw more light on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
case 2+a: doSomething();
          break:
case 4-a: doSomethingElse();
          break;
```

What do you do when `a==1`?

There are several possible answers, including

- Run all applicable cases, in order
- Run all applicable cases, in arbitrary order
- Run the first applicable case
- Run any one applicable case
- The behaviour is undefined
- Raise a well-defined error

The problem is, none of the resolutions is preferred over the others. Moreover, all run contrary to the original simple rationale of the switch statement, which is providind a high(ish) level abstraction of a fast, precomputed indexed jump table.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is usually superfluous, and on a compiler level you want a jump to a fixed address. Just put the dependency of the variable in the `switch` expression

```
switch(a-b) 
{ 
  case 4: printf("hii"); 
}
```